# How can I create new lists of a sorted list

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to sort a list by date and then create new lists containing only items with that date.
In this example there would be one list with items of the date 21.01.2021 and a list with items of date 28.01.2021 etc, so that there a three different lists at the end.

```
  List<Example> exampleList = [Example("Marc", "21.01.2021"), Example("Tobi", "21.01.2021"), 
                              Example("Lucy", "28.01.2021"), Example("Tim", "29.01.2021")];
  
  exampleList.sort((a,b) => a.date.compareTo(b.date));
  exampleList.forEach((value) {
    print(value.name);
  });
 
}


class Example{
  String name;
  String date;
  
  Example(this.name, this.date);
}
```

Comment: So the end goal is to separate your objects into its own list for each day?

Comment: Yes exactly. For this example there should be three different list at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you mean by having three separate lists but check this example where I uses a `Map<String, List<Example>>` to split your dates into its own list:

```
void main() {
  final exampleList = [
    Example("Marc", "21.01.2021"),
    Example("Tobi", "21.01.2021"),
    Example("Lucy", "28.01.2021"),
    Example("Tim", "29.01.2021")
  ];

  final exampleMap = exampleList.fold<Map<String, List<Example>>>(
      {},
      (map, element) => map
        ..update(element.date, (list) => list..add(element),
            ifAbsent: () => [element]));

  print(exampleMap);
  // {21.01.2021: [Marc, Tobi], 28.01.2021: [Lucy], 29.01.2021: [Tim]}
}

class Example {
  String name;
  String date;

  Example(this.name, this.date);

  @override
  String toString() => name;
}
```

If you want to get the lists you can just use the `.values` on `exampleMap`.